# Using bash -c with loops and standard output redirection

Tags: bash

Why does the standard output from the following commands differ?

command1:

```
for ((i=0; i<10; i=i+1)); do echo $i; done
```

command2:

```
bash -c "for ((i=0; i<10; i=i+1)); do echo $i; done"
```

command1 prints the integers 1 to 10 on a separate line, as expected.  command2 prints 10 on each line.

What do I need to do to get command2 to print the same thing as command1?

The long story:

I often need to run an executable on a large number of files and capture the output of the entire process.  I use a for loop similar to command1 in a separate file called my_script.sh.

I can then get the output using:

```
bash my_script.sh > results.txt
```

Since it's a bit of a pain to create a separate my_script.sh file for trivial for loops, I was hoping to achieve the same thing by using "bash -c", but ran into this problem.

Thanks for any suggestions.  Looking forward to replies.
Misha

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> What do I need to do to get command2 to print the same thing as command1?

You need to fix this line:

```
bash -c "for ((i=0; i<10; i=i+1)); do echo $i; done"
```

To say this instead:

```
bash -c "for ((i=0; i<10; i=i+1)); do echo \$i; done"
```

What's happening is that the `$i` sequence is being interpreted by the shell you are running bash from, and it is substituting *its own* `i` variable into the string before passing it off to the new bash instance to be executed.  So by the time the new bash sees the string, it is:

```
for ((i=0; i<10; i=i+1)); do echo 10; done
```

Assuming that `i` contained the value "10".

(When I first ran the second script, which I did before running the first, it wrote out 10 blank lines, because I had no `i` variable defined, and so it was substituting in the empty string.)

Comment: Or you could just change the double quotes to single quotes.

Comment: Yup, either approach will work.  Anything that gets the outer shell to treat the `$` literally.

Comment: `$i` would be `10` if you ran command 2 after command 1, of course.

Comment: Thank you.  Using the \ escape and using single quotes instead of double quotes both solve the problem.

Comment: Just don't combine the two solutions, or you'll have an anti-solution. ;)

Comment: @misha: On StackOverflow, "Thank you. That solves my problem" is expressed as a green tick to the left of the answer. Occasionally with an upvote.