# How to force /bin/bash interpreter for oneliners

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a one liner bash command that is executed with python os.system()

```
for FILENAME in mydir/PRE_*; do echo $FILENAME `printf ${FILENAME:0:12}; printf ${FILENAME:23}`; done;
```

It loops through all files in a directory and renames them, to take chars 12-23 out of the filename. The command works fine when I execute it through bash with my server login, but when I executed it through python with the web user it throws errors.

I found out that this is because the web user's default shell is /bin/sh instead of /bin/bash.

I am able to log in with that user and change the shell to /bin/bash.

So the question is can I force the one-liner to execute with /bin/bash without changing the default shell for the user?

Comment: You can accomplish the same with pure Python, without shelling out to `bash` at all. I'd recommend that instead.

Comment: you are right, I did the bash cause it seemed a simple one liner, and kinda forgot that python can do the same thing. Code is much cleaner with naitive python, but still worth knowing how I can force the bash interpreter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you can call it as:

```
/bin/bash -c '$cmd'
```

Where `$cmd` is the full command line.

Comment: I had a problem with the double quotes, replaced them with single quotes and it worked. Explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176347/using-bash-c-with-loops-and-standard-output-redirection

Comment: Yes that is correct and thanks for the link. I edited answer accordingly.

Comment: On FreeBSD bash would be installed in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: The portable approach would be `/usr/bin/env bash`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = Popen(['/bin/bash','-'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
cmdout = p.communicate(input='uname -a\nuptime\nprintenv\n')[0]
print(cmdout)
```

Comment: On FreeBSD bash would be installed in `/usr/local/bin`.